# Get x,y,value 1D arrays from 2D numpy array (linear indexing)

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a 2D array like the one below:

```
array([3, 6, 7
       1,-1, 3])
```

I would like to get in 3 separate arrays the `x`, `y` and `value` of the array . In other words:

```
x      = [0, 1, 0,  1, 0, 1]
y      = [0, 0, 1,  1, 2, 2]
values = [3, 1, 6, -1, 7, 3]
```

How can I do this?

For reference, this is what MATLAB calls [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like:

```
x, y = np.indices(array.shape)
x = x.ravel(order='F')
y = y.ravel(order='F')
values = array.ravel(order='F')
```

Comment: `np.mgrid` is a nice tool for something like this +1.

Comment: FWIW I often use `np.indices(a.shape)` instead of `mgrid`.

Comment: Thanks @DSM - Any reasons to believe that `np.indices(a.shape)` would be better/faster than `mgrid`? Just wondering.

Comment: @user815423426: some quick `timeit` tests suggests `np.indices` is faster on larger arrays, but I prefer it because it's higher-level and works for all dimensions, not for performance reasons.  You can always use `timeit` to see which is faster for your use case, but I'd be very surprised if this turned out to be a bottleneck anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `scipy` installed along with `numpy`, you can use its `sparse` module

```
from scipy import sparse
x = np.array([[3,6,7],[1,-1,3]])
M=sparse.coo_matrix(x.T)
M.data
# array([ 3,  1,  6, -1,  7,  3])
M.col
# array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
M.row
# array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

Looking at `coo_matrix` I see that `nonzero()` is used to get the indices:

```
row,col = x.T.nonzero()
data = x.T[row,col]
```

If there could be zeros in `x`, you'd have use a work around like `np.nonzero(np.ones(x.T.shape))`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def xyval(A):
    x, y = np.indices(A.shape)
    return x.ravel(), y.ravel(), A.ravel()
```

Comment: @Sumurai8 I disagree - how is this any worse than a typical answer consisting of "How about something like this: `<code snippet>`". The example is so simple that I don't think a load of additional commentary would really add anything useful.

Comment: That would be just as bad. A typical answer can at least contain a link to the documentation of the functions used. If OP had actually made effort to try something, you could have added where they went wrong. If the answer -was- trivial (ala everyone should have known how to do it), OP wouldn't ask the question in the first place. If someone with a similar problem comes around, the answer has no value, because they can't simply copy/paste the code, and the answer contains no further information hinting at how they can solve their problem.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I note that 3 of the other answers, including the highest voted one, fall into this category. The OP asks "How can I do X?". I provide a clear, succinct example showing one way to do X. Simple examples like this are _definitely_ of value to other people with similar questions. I'm not a fan of rubbing the documentation in the OP's face - if he/she had a question about some particular function or module that could be succinctly answered from the docs then it would be appropriate, but in this case it would just be gratuitous.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[3, 6, 7],
              [1,-1, 3]])

n_rows, n_cols = a.shape


temp_x = np.repeat(np.arange(n_rows)[np.newaxis, :], n_cols, axis=0) 
# construction of x can probably be simplified
x = temp_x.ravel()    
y = np.repeat(np.arange(n_cols), n_rows)        
values = a.ravel(order='F')
```

Result:

```
>>> x
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
>>> y
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
>>> values
array([ 3,  1,  6, -1,  7,  3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `values` array can be attained by using the [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) method of a 2D array (matrix).  Then it's just a matter of constructing the `x` and `y` arrays to contain the proper indices.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

a = np.array([[3, 6, 7],
              [1,-1, 3]])

idxs   = np.array(list(itertools.product(*map(range, a.shape))))
x      = idxs[:,0]
y      = idxs[:,1]
values = a.flatten()
```

Testing this:

```
>>> x
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
>>> y
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
>>> values
array([ 3,  6,  7,  1, -1,  3])
>>> a[0,0]
3
>>> a[0,1]
6
>>> a[0,2]
7
>>> a[1,0]
1
>>> a[1,1]
-1
>>> a[1,2]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do 2 loops (or nested list comprehension) with 2 enumerate(iterable) inside.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ar1=np.ones([3,4])
>>> ar1
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> ar1[::2,::3]=-1
>>> ar1[::3,:21]=-2
>>> ar1
array([[-2., -2., -2., -2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1., -1.]])


>>> x=[];y=[];values=[]
>>> for i,ari in enumerate(ar1):
...   for j,valj in enumerate(ari):
...     print i,j,valj
...     x+=[i];y+=[j];values+=[valj]
...
0 0 -2.0
0 1 -2.0
0 2 -2.0
0 3 -2.0
1 0 1.0
1 1 1.0
1 2 1.0
1 3 1.0
2 0 -1.0
2 1 1.0
2 2 1.0
2 3 -1.0
```

Comment: Usually answers give a bit more details. With that this answer would definitely be more useful.

Comment: @Trilarion I updated my answer with code sample, let me know if it works for you. not sure about performance.